# Two dimensions in a cube don't connect to each other

Tags: sql-server, ssas, olap

I have a problem in SSAS with my cube, where I have 2 dimensions and a fact table. The problem is, when I want to analyze expenses for each employee, and from which department that employee is, none of the employees show up as being connected to any department... Simply put, Dim_Department is not connected with Dim_Employees, and I dont understand why.

Some info about the tables -

every employee has a DepartmentId, and there are only 6 departments. In the Fact_Expenses, not every row has a EmployeeId, or a DepartmentId (I think the problem is here), meaning there can be NULL rows for those columns.

Still, as I understand it, if the dimensions are connected, every employee should be able to have it's department connected to it. There is no problem in the database with an INNER JOIN, so how should I connect the tables in an SSAS cube?

[Cube in a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1dXA.png)

Comment: I'm guessing this is a multi-dimensional cube?  And is there a relationship intentionally defined directly between Dim_Department and Dim_Employees as in the image?  Also, do the arrows represent the filtering direction?  The dimensions should be filtering the fact table, i.e. a one-to-many relationship with the dimension tables on the one side, which judging by their PKs looks like the intent.

Comment: Yes, it is a multi-dimensional cube in SSAS. Yes, there is a relationship between Dim_Department and Dim_Employees. And yes, the arrows represent the filtering direction, as done automatically by SSAS, and it should be correct, because it works with other dimensions.

Comment: I'm not familiar with your data, but the dimensions should be filtering the fact table.  You may need to change to relationship filtering direction in SSDT, with the dimensions (on the one side, with the PK) filtering the fact table (on the many side, with the FK).  If you get an error for duplicate values on the one side, you'll want to check the source tables.  And judging by your setup, there should only be relationships from the dimensions to the fact tables, not from one dimension to another.